# Раскрытие пароля подключения в Oracle

Tags: oracle, пароль

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, с помощью чего можно раскрыть пароль подключения в ORACLE? Забыл пароль на пользователя system, а переставлять целиком ORACLE нет желания...

Comment: С помощью прямого перебора

Comment: Here I found a good explanation for resetting and reusing an Oracle account password http://dbpilot.net/2018/01/15/resetting-an-oracle-account-password Привет всем, По указанной ссылке имеется хорошее обьяснение как сбросить или востановить старый пароль от Oracle.
http://dbpilot.net/2018/01/15/resetting-an-oracle-account-password

Answer (score 3):

Пароли хранят в зашифрованном виде только придурки, а в Oracle точно работают не придурки :) Реальные пацаны хранят хэш от пароля, причем хэш "соленого" пароля.

Стандартная схема хранения паролей это:

1. Отдельно хранится [соль(Salt)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) к паролям
2. Хранится значение [хэш функции](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_function)=хэш(пароль+соль)

Применительно к Oracle [схема опубликована](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/special/?id=oracle_pass&ref=911) и состоит в том, что в качестве соли используется username, причем схема case-insensitive. В качестве хэш функции используется двойная схема шифрования DES в режиме сцепления блоков по CBC со значением ключа в первом проходе: `0x0123456789ABCDEF`, при втором проходе в качестве ключа используется значение последнего блока предыдущего прохода в псевдокоде выглядит так:

```
DES[CBC](DES[CBC](uppercase(username+password)));
```

Значение хэша пароля и username можно посмотреть так:

```
select username, password from dba_users;
```

При такой схеме шифрования наиболее эффективна будет [атака по словарю](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). То есть схема взлома будет такая:

1. Написать на С/C++/Java функцию реализующую описанный выше хэш
2. Найти в сети словарь - [например здесь](http://www.skullsecurity.org/wiki/index.php/Passwords)
3. Запустить свою функцию которая будет перебирать словарь и сравнивать конечное значение с хэшем хранимым в указанной таблице.

Есть еще вариант обратиться в [форум AntiChat](http://forum.antichat.ru/) - там тусуются ребята на спор взламывающие хэши паролей.

P.S. Возможно схема хранения паролей в Oracle уже сменена.

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus / as sysdba

alter user SYSTEM identified by 123;
exit;

Answer (score -1):

Пароли хранятся в зашифрованом виде, врядли удастся их расшифровать.
Попробуйте удалить этого пользователя, или пароль, а затем создать нового.